# How to ignore environment variables in REG_EXPAND_SZ?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I'm writing a small C# program that changes some hardcoded paths in the windows registry. My problems are REG_EXPAND_SZ Values that contain environment variables. Example:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Installer\
```

If i query this value using [GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), i get the path for %APPDATA%. But i dont want it to lookup the environment variable.

I cant exclude such values because they may contain hardcoded paths that are important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvalueoptions.aspx) option when you call [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzxd58z1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Thats why you should not use Google when searching for the docs, i found Registry.GetValue() but actually used RegistryKey.GetValue() in my code - which has the mentioned option.